# file missing from Desktop screen but can be seen using "ls" under the Desktop directory

Tags: centos, files, ls

I downloaded some files onto desktop. After typing `ls` under the `Desktop` directory, I can see these files. However, I cannot see the icons on my desktop corresponding to the files I see with `ls`. I use CentOs.

Comment: check that the `/Desktop` directory that you type `ls` on isn't of the `root` user or any other user that the desktop.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two possible issues:

1. If you have no icons at all on your desktop, you might have accidentally turned them off (ie, made them not appear). Gnome can do this which is the default desktop environment CentOS ships with I think
2. If there are other icons, then you are probably running `ls` in a `Desktop` directory which isn't your own but another user's (as @Hanan N. suggests, it could be roots). `cd` into the `Desktop` directory and look at the output of `pwd`. It should be `/home/<your_username>/Desktop`.

Comment: Hi, I just check my Desktop directory, it is /home/myself/Desktop

Comment: Can you post the output of `ls -l /path/file`, where `path` is the path to the file and `file` is the file itself.

Comment: ls -l /home/myself/Desktop/Note_ch6.pdf
ls: /home/myself/Desktop/Note_ch6.pdf: No such file or directory

Comment: So the file definitely isn't there. Either the desktop directory you were looking at at the beginning and the directory displayed ON your desktop are not the same. I would copy/move the file over from the non-visible desktop directory to your GUI desktop directory.